# Longest Path in an undirected unweighted graph

Tags: algorithm, math, graph

I came across a problem where I have to find out the longest path in a given graph. I have list of edges ( eg.{AB, BC} ) which states there is an edge between vertices/nodes (A,B,C). Now i want to figure out the longest path possible (not repeating the vertex) such that it covers maximum nodes starting from any vertex/node.

What can be the best way to solve this?
I have to implement this as a program.

I looked up google for
Minimum Spanning Tree, Dijkstra's Alogorithms , and many more. but can't figure out what would suit best for this problem.

Any help or reading references would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think this is probably NP-complete.

Comment: Actually at first glance I am thinking of using MST on the inversely weighted graph. So basically, if the graph has weights 2,5,8,3,7; then I would invert the weights to get 1/2,1/5,1/8/,1/3,1/7. Would that work?

Comment: @KonsolLabapen tl;dr: No, because MST is polynomial in time (take the edges in increasing order as long as you don't form a cycle).  To explain that quick answer: this problem is NP-complete, so a polynomial time algorithm such as MST would imply P=NP.  I think we may safely assume that if proving P=NP were that easy, someone would have done so already.

Comment: How about using Dijkstra on it. I mean, the same argument as I made above, but instead of using MST, use Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm. The argument being, since the shortest path is the inverse of the longest path, then taking the inverse of the weights and calculating the shortest path should in fact give the answer to the orginal question. From purely analysing the logic proposition: where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Since your question doesn't speak whether the Graph is Cyclic or Not you have two options:

**Option1**:*Graph is DAG*

You are Lucky, you can use topological sort on the graph and get the longest path!

**Option 2**:*Graph is NOT DAG:*

Use the Hamiltonian Algorithm as mentioned in the Comments!

Answer (score 1):

This is NP-Hard.

You can solve Hamiltonian Path problem, if you can solve this problem.

(Longest path = |V| <=> Hamiltonial Path).

So, just pick up any algorithm for Travelling Salesman Problem. Give all the edges weight one.

I heard a dynamic programming version is particularly nice.

Comment: @CodieCodeMonkey: The equivalence should be enough to figure out that TSP algos can be used. Anyway. Updated. This question is likely a dupe, though.

Comment: My recommendation would be to start with [tag:traveling-salesman] ;)

Comment: Not all graphs have Hamiltonian paths.  Any graph with cut-edges doesn't.  But I think you're almost right: whereas if a Hamiltonian path exists you start from any vertex and enumerate all paths back to that vertex with backtracking, for this problem you would have to try multiple starting vertices to have all possible paths covered.

Comment: @Teepeemm: Traveling salesman doesn't work because the edges you get may not be in the graph!

Comment: @CodieCodeMonkey In my vocabulary, a path doesn't need to end where it starts, so I think our disagreement is just a matter of definitions.  I agree that a traveling salesman algorithm won't solve this problem without modification, but any idea that applies to the traveling salesman will also apply here.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to finding Hamiltonian paths, this needs to be solved by backtracking.

For each vertex in the graph, initialize a `path` list.  Each element of `path` will contain a vertex, and a list of vertices (`adj`) which can be reached from that vertex.  That is, `path[i] -> (v, adj)`.  We'll make it a rule that the vertices in `adj[v]` must not be vertices that occur earlier in `path`.

`path[i+1]` is built from `path[i]` by letting `path[i+1].v = pop(path[i].adj)`, and setting `path[i+1].adj` equal the adjacent vertices of `path[i+1].v` that are not yet in the path.  If there is no element of `path[i].adj` to pop, we've reached a dead end.  If the path is longer than the largest path found so far record it.

Now pop all the elements from `path` until you find one that doesn't have an empty `adj` list (this is called backtracking).  After backtracking, either the last `path` element has a non-empty `adj` list, or the path is empty, i.e.  you've backtracked to the beginning.  If the path is not empty, extend the path as before.  If the path is empty, choose a new starting vertex and begin again.

Eventually all possible paths are enumerated, so the longest path found is your answer.

You may be able to find ways to short-cut this process, possibly using cut-edges (aka bridge edges).

Comment: I like the approach (+1), but am not sure about the last paragraph (assuming that a bridge-edge is a cut edge that disconnects the graph).  If I have a graph that is a simple path of length 10, and add an edge at the middle vertex, won't that become a cut edge separating the path from the added vertex?

Comment: @Teepeemm, Hmmmm, I agree that it isn't clear that you can use cut-edges (aka bridge-edges).  I think I'll just remove that, although I suspect that if we really want to get clever we can leverage them in certain cases.  I don't think we want to work that hard here.

Answer (score 0):

Give all edges weight 1. The non-existent, give weight n+1. Now apply TSP.

Leave something for the OP to work out, but alas apparently this was harder than I assumed it was.